# Sphinx doc: Process image directive to create HTML with base64 image data URI

Tags: python-sphinx

When Sphinx compiles an RST file with image directive, it results in a HTML that has  tag where the "src" attribute points to the image file.

Sample RST file

```
..image:: path/image.jpg
```

Resulting HTML

```
<img src='path/image.jpg'>
```

This means that the image is not contained within the HTML. The image file is a separate document from the HTML.

How can image directive be processed such that the resulting HTML has the  tag with 'src' attribute containing base64 encoded image data as shown below

```
<img width="64" height="69" alt="Treehouse Logo" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABF...">
```

In the above example, the image data is embedded into the HTML. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The `image` directive does not support this. I think you will have to create a custom directive.

Comment: You could use the [`raw` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through), but you would need to already know the image data in base64. I don't know of any Sphinx extension that does that already.